# Put multiple classes in Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I'm scraping a news website and I need to extract an element with multiple classes. My original code looks like this:

```
var index = $(this).attr('class');
```

And then append it as text to span:

```
$('.element').append('<span>.'+index+'</span>');
```

This works good for a single class, but when multiple classes are given it doesn't work(meaning I can't do my function). The reason for this is that the Jquery statement should have classes seperated by comma. So calling multiple classes will look like this in my code:

```
<span> .class1 class2 class3 </span>
```

But Jquery needs the comma's and dots like so:

```
 <span> .class1, .class2, .class3 </span>
```

What can I do to add the comma's and dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply split the string by *spaces* into an array, then join it together again back into a string, and you'll be all set.

```
var index = $('div').attr('class').split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {
    index[i] = '.' + index[i];
}

index = index.join(', ');
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fu8QH/)**

Result would be `.class1, .class2, .class3`